# log file viewer for java applications

Tags: java, logging

All,
I was exploring if there can be a tool that helps me to this:

1. View a log file in reverse chronological order i.e. I want to see the latest log statements being written to a log file at the top of the screen and not scroll all the way down every time log file is updated.
2. may be pause while viewing so that while I am reading or analyzing my log files, it does not refresh the screen.

Is it possible?

I am using log4j for logging in my j2ee application.
Thanks.

Comment: This is surprising.. how come this question got down voted? is this insignificant question or offensive?

Comment: Is "tail -f logfile.log" enough ? (logs are automatically scrolled and you can pause it when you need to do it)

Comment: @Guido I am on windows XP. I am sorry I should have mentioned this earlier. The tail tool I am talking about is from here: http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html). Although it doesn't appear to be actively developed, you can:

- toggle the option of automatically scrolling to the bottom. You can also order the log records in the reverse chronological order, to display the most recent records first, so the previous option is no longer required.
- pause log record collection. This will discard any log records and will not update the display until you resume collection.

Comment: thanks, but since chainsaw is not actively developed and also does not diget the normal log file without a log4j xml file, it's some over head. I was looking for simplified tool like tail or similar.

Comment: It is actively being developed..just no release in a long time..check out the latest developer snapshot here, and release notes from the help menu: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: In my opinions Chainsaw development is not so active. Last commit was 2011-10-03.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/). You can pause scrolling to bottom and turn off adding new log events.
You can watch [screen capture on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESCa-X8l4OE).

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of OtrosLogViewer

Answer (score 1):

Use LogMX from [www.logmx.com](http://www.logmx.com). I've worked with Chainsaw and LogFactor5, but in the end, LogMX is worth the money. Use Chainsaw if you want something free.

Answer (score 0):

Check [mtail](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/mtail/) (or monkeytail). It's not exactly what you are searching for but maybe worth a look.

[Watch all of your logs using monkeytail](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/2008/06/watch-all-of-your-logs-using-monkeytail.html)

Some closed question in SO:

- [The best Tail GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133821/the-best-tail-gui)
- [Best tail (log file visualization) freeware tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113121/best-tail-log-file-visualization-freeware-tool)